# Cache / queue for high frequency writes

Tags: php, sql, caching, memcached, gearman

Assume a (PHP) web application with X00,000 requests per minute, and a SQL database with about the same number of entries.

Each request will trigger a few (<5) db reads, and one db write (update, mostly). I am mainly worried about performance issues being caused by the writes, and looking for solutions to increase possible requests per minute.

What solutions would you suggest, how would you go about implementing it, and why?

Things I thought about include a cache to write to, which is synced with the db once every *some time-interval*, or a queue like Gearman, or simply SQL's insert delayed.

However, since the same load is expected to be constant, insert delayed will probably not help much when server load is constantly at >90%, so I am looking for ways to significantly reduce the server load compared to single writes.

Thanks

Comment: Is the update mandatory after reads?

Comment: In the assumed problem, yes. Consider it a status report being sent by some device, although this update may not be more than a timestamp for last_seen.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as too broad (although it also seems to be opinion-based and asking for a software recommendation).  I will add, though, that you may have a use case where a NOSQL database with relaxed ACID functionality could be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Close the question.. come on stackoverflow. I find this question very appropriate, since it poses a specific problem (high # of writes) and asks for a good solution. 
Still, thanks for adding the second half.

Comment: I'd consider pushing to a queue, and perhaps allow the queue consumer to bundle multiple inserts or updates together wherever possible

Comment: I could be wrong, but I suspect this might come in handy - turning off autocommit and not using explicit transactions should allow the OS to schedule writes instead MySQL forcing the drive to write the data. You're going to completely lose the D in ACID though if you do this. Alternative is what Mark Baker mentioned, using a queue and bundle multiple updates  - which is what I'd do. I also find this question valid and potentially valuable, it does make sense in the given context of our development life.

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the table you are also reading, then yes, these updates will slow down reads, because they wil invalidate the MySQL query-cache and possible table locking. One common example is table for product details, where you are updating visit counts.

Simple approach is not updating the main table, but instead use separate table for the changing values (for example `product_views`) and alter your queries to use JOIN for fetching the values. Using this approach your main (and big) table will be mostly static and unaffected by query-cache invalidation and locking.

More advanced approach would be to NOT use UPDATEs, but INSERTs. Instead of updating a row on every pageview, INSERT new value into temp table (e.g. `product_views_temp`) - so each view will be 1 row. Then schedule a cron job for example every 5 minutes to do a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_views_temp GROUP BY prod_id` and based on the numbers update the main table (should be possible in 1 query). Main benefit is that these INSERTs are faster and you can have the counts in the main table if you need for whatever reason. Little drawback is that that there will be little delay before visitors will see the updated counts.

**EDIT:** If you can afford to lose the counts data for those 5 minutes, you can make it super-fast by creating that temp table with MySQL [MEMORY storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html). They are very fast for INSERTs (but can be little slower for UPDATEs). When the server crashes / shutdowns, the table itself still exists, but its contents is lost.

You can also use the MEMORY engine for session data (it doesn't matter if users need to log-in again after an unexpected server crash as it is something which will not happen often).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Separate tables for the frequently updated value(s) would probably be fine, as would a little delay. However my main worry is not that the updates will obstruct the reads, but rather that the sheer amount of database transactions, a large fraction of which is writes (i.e. especially slow), will be a bottleneck for the entire application, and allow for less requests per minute (read: updates per minute) than it might with a decent cache or queue. Am I making sense to you?

Comment: If your database is on a RAID controller with battery backed write cache, then the INSERTs will be very fast as the actual writes will be done in the background and should not affect the speed of your application. You can also use temp tables in memory...

Comment: A quick look at the mysql memory engine showed that they themselves say  it is suitable for "A read-only or read-mostly data access pattern (limited updates).", while my access pattern is almost only update. However MySQL cluster might be better for writes. Gotta see if this is an option for MariaDB.
The DB will be in some cloud, so the assumption is that it is properly backed up.

Comment: When all the writes are done in the background, I don't have my clients waiting (which I would not care that much about in this specific case) until the query returns, BUT if the server is not capable of writing X00,000 updates per minute, then that won't help as the queue just grows indefinitely. But then again, if I can do one grouped UPDATE that'll be faster than single queries.

Comment: On another note, in this particular usecase, the updated data indeed is something like session data, so storing it in memory (mysql memory storage engine, or possibly just use memcached) might in the end be a very good idea. Your suggestion with a temporary table seems much like a queue like Gearman, just the overhead might be more if one chooses to write the INSERTs to disk.

Anyway, thanks for the ideas!

Comment: The manual mentiones read-only pattern, but it is also applicable for write-mostly workload. Mixing read-write for memory engine is not efficient due to locking.

Comment: I see. I will make some tests.